# string concatenate in group by function with other aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-server-group-concat

Is it possible to concatenate strings with one or more of other group by function like sum, avg, count etc .

Say I have the following table

```
Id Name Order Value  
1  a    1     100  
2  b    2     200  
3  c    1     300  
4  d    1     100  
5  e    2     300
```

Now if I want the result to be something of this sort

```
Order Name   Value Count  
1     a,c,d  500   3  
2     b,e    500   2
```

How can i achieve the same using a query on SQL server.

Answer (score 7):

Sample table

```
create table t123 (Id int, Name varchar(10), [Order] int, Value int)
insert t123 select 
1,'a','1',100 union all select
2,'b','2',200 union all select
3,'c','1',300 union all select
4,'d','1',100 union all select
5,'e','2',300
```

Query for SQL Server 2005 and above

```
select a.[order], STUFF((
    select ','+b.name
    from t123 b
    where b.[order] = a.[order]
    order by b.name
    for xml path('a'), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') Name,
    SUM(a.value) value,
    COUNT(*) [count]
from t123 a
group by a.[order]
```

Output

```
order       Name         value       count
----------- ------------ ----------- -----------
1           a,c,d        500         3
2           b,e          500         2
```

Comment: Can u please explain what the hell is going on here.. my table is not a real table, its a result set from join of multiple tables.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this.

- I placed your original query in a CTE.
- Then I selected from it, and grouped by the order.
- Then I cross applied with a subquery that gets a comma-delimited set of names for each order in the outer query.
- Since I also selected the names column, I had to also group by the names column.

Like this:

```
;WITH cte(id, n, o, v) as (
   SELECT Id, Name, Order, Value FROM ....
)
SELECT o, names, SUM(v), COUNT(*)
FROM cte AS outer
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Name+',' 
    FROM cte AS inner 
    WHERE outer.o = inner.o 
    ORDER BY Name FOR XML PATH('')
) n(names)
group by o, names
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MS SQL Server 2005 or newer you can create user-defined aggregate functions.

[MSDN: CREATE AGGREGATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

[MSDN: Invoking CLR User-Defined Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)