# Concatenate grouped rows

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I would like to know is it possible from this table

```
ID   Price    ServiceID
1    50       11
1    -10      12
2    100      11
2    20       11
```

to group by ID, sum the price and concatenate serviceID, something like this:

```
ID   Price    ServiceID
1    40       11,12
2    120      11
```

It is rather simple to group by ID and sum the price, but concatenate service IDs what is troubling me.

Thank you for participating.

Comment: I always thought normalization was overrated too :)

Comment: Why do you want to?  This is considered by most to be a SQL Anti-Pattern; if we know why, we may be ale to recommend a different, better, approach...

Comment: Duplicate of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573528/string-concatenate-in-group-by-function-with-other-aggregate-functions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579440/how-to-concatenate-all-strings-from-a-certain-column-for-each-group

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
select t.id, sum(t.price)
    , stuff((
        select distinct ',' + cast(t2.ServiceID as varchar(max))
        from @t t2
        where t2.id = t.id
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
from @t t
group by t.id
```

Output:

```
----------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           40,00                 11,12
2           120,00                11
```

Comment: This does indeed work, however, for more complex examples, I get Column XYZ is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mattpm, Create a separate question.