# Combine Row Results SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I looked up several answers that didn't seem to quite work for me, or I used them incorrectly with my query.

**Current query:**

```
SELECT
    PartNo,
    SubPartNo
FROM
    Materials
```

**Current Results:**

```
+--------+-----------+
| PartNo | SubPartNo |
+--------+-----------+
|    541 |      5451 |
|    545 |      5451 |
+--------+-----------+
```

**Desired Results:**

```
+----------+-----------+
|  PartNo  | SubPartNo |
+----------+-----------+
| 541, 545 |      5451 |
+----------+-----------+
```

The result doesn't necessarily need the comma. I am sure this is an easy fix but my limited know-how is slowing me down.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server string aggregation".  You may decide you can live with the original format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate grouped rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139472/concatenate-grouped-rows)

Comment: use `FOR XML XPATH`: https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: Thank you, that link really helped. I saw the XML path on one post but without explanation I wasn't really following it. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments directing me to https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/ my question was answered.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    matl1.SubPartNo,
    STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + matl2.PartNo
            FROM Materials as matl2
            WHERE matl2.SubPartNo = matl1.SubPartNo
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'')
FROM
    Materials as matl1
```